# Hauppauge HVR-950Q - Linux - Signal Processing for extra data like subtitles

Tags: hardware, linux

I have a Hauppauge HVR-950Q running on a stripped down debian. I am trying to use the Hauppauge HVR-950Q from the command line to parse subtitles and build a library of accurate subtitles. I am not sure how to start on this one being that I want to do all this programmatically in the background. Some information can be found [at linuxtv.org HVR-950Q](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-950Q) but I do not see any types of API nor can I find documentation so far.

How would I probe this or any other device in such a way that I would start "finding" things I need?

Comment: Doubtful.. since all you have to do is save the recording the dump it from there. https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~macbeth/notes.html but perhaps you want something more complex or realtime than the save mpeg and dump method allows.

Comment: I would like realtime, and absolutely do not want to save full recordings. Space is very limited, and I have no need for the actual mpeg feeds just the subtitles.

Comment: However, cb88, thank you for the link I will see what I can gain from it.

Comment: well you could probably look at mplayer/vlc/ffmpeg and figure out how they parse the stream and do the same thing...